# How to implement Multi Processing or Threads in a function?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following functions in python:

```py
def functionA(bandwidth, range_start, range_end):
    for bandwidth in range(range_start, range_end, 1):
        os.system('iperf -c ' + server_address + ' -u -p 50001 -b ' + str(bandwidth) + 'M -i 1')

def functionB(bandwidth, range_start, range_end):
    for bandwidth in range(range_start, range_end, 1):
        os.system('iperf -c ' + server_address + ' -u -p 50001 -b ' + str(bandwidth) + 'M -i 1'
```

I aim to keep running `Iperf` or literally this `functionA` when the `bandwidth` value reaches a certain value (let's say 20) I mean keep having the value 20 for `bandwidth` variable, while another `functionB` starts to run after reaching 20. In meantime, `functionB` keeps running also when `bandwidth` value reaches a different certain value (let's say 40). That time, `functionA` stops having the static value 20 for `bandwidth`, but it increases to the infinite. While `functionB` keeps having 40 as a static value for `bandwidth`.

First, I thought to use `while` loop like the following:

```py
while True:
    os.system('iperf -c ' + server_address + ' -u -p 50001 -b ' + str(bandwidth) + 'M -i 1')
```

However, it cannot be done as long as the function A is in infinite loop.

I thought also to use Threads and MultiProcessing, but I don't see how it can be applied in here. It seems too complicated for me.

**Edit**

Let's say we are running **functionA**, if you can see the *bandwidth* is increasing using *range()*, but when it reaches the *bandwidth* value 20, it starts the process of *iperf* with static value of *bandwidth* 20. 
At the same time, **functionB** starts to run and when it reaches the *bandwidth* value 40, it runs *iperf* with static value *bandwidth* 40. That time, when **functionB** start generating static *bandwidth* 40, **functionA** stops iperf(generating 20Mbps traffic), to start another or its process of generating traffic that starts from 20 to the infinite (using *range()*). At the same time, **functionB** keeps running an infinite *iperf* process with 40 bandwidth static value

that function with value bandwidth 20 where it stopped in first time. While functionB keeps running iperf with the static bandwidth value of 40.

Comment: The two function look identical — why do you need two of the same thing?

Comment: @martineau they are basically doing the same process, but there are changes in parameters. In fact I have given a simplified code just to understand. I deleted some parts of code of both function.

Comment: Do you want the running of `iperf` started _within_ `functionA` or `functionB` to run concurrently with each other or sequentially?

Comment: @martineau I've just edited the questions. Please, check it.

Comment: Sorry, your recent edit doesn't really clarify what you want to do. That said, I think you _may_ be able to do whatever it is by using Python generators (**not** multiprocessing or threads). See this youtube video  of a talk by David Beazley titled [Generators: The Final Frontier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1twn9kLmYg) he gave at PyCon 2014.